# Getting NullPointerException while fetching property from repository in ATG

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce, atg-droplet

I'm trying to fetch properties like first name and last name from profile repository, displaying it in jsp using droplet. Below is my sample code:
SampleDroplet.java

```
public class SampleDroplet extends DynamoServlet {

private Repository mProfileRepository;
@Override
public void service(DynamoHttpServletRequest pReq, DynamoHttpServletResponse pRes)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String lFirstName = null;
    String lLastName = null;
    String lProfileId = pReq.getParameter("profileId");     
    try {
        RepositoryItem lItem = getProfileRepository().getItem(lProfileId, "user");
        lFirstName = (String) lItem.getPropertyValue("firstName");
        lLastName = (String) lItem.getPropertyValue("lastName");
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pReq.setParameter("firstName", lFirstName);
    pReq.setParameter("lastName", lLastName);
    pReq.serviceParameter("output", pReq, pRes);
}
```

SampleDroplet.properties

```
$class=com.tap.droplet.SampleDroplet
scope=global
profileRepository=/atg/userProfiling/ProfileAdaptarRepository
```

SampleDroplet.jsp

```
<dsp:page>
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/userprofiling/Profile" var="profile" />
<dsp:importbean bean="/com/tap/droplet/SampleDroplet" />
<dsp:getvalueof var="profileId" bean="Profile.id"/>
    <dsp:droplet name="SampleDroplet">
        <dsp:param name="profileId" value="${profileId}" />
        <dsp:oparam name="output">
            Profile's First Name : <dsp:valueof param="firstName"/>
                      Last Name : <dsp:valueof param="lastName"/>
        </dsp:oparam>
    </dsp:droplet>
</dsp:page>
```

I've tried displaying profileId in jsp it is working. But when i passed it to droplet it is showing NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tap.droplet.SampleDroplet.service(SampleDroplet.java:26)
at atg.servlet.DynamoServlet.service(DynamoServlet.java:152)
at atg.taglib.dspjsp.DropletTag.invokeServlet(DropletTag.java:420)
at atg.taglib.dspjsp.DropletTag.doAfterBody(DropletTag.java:705)
at     jsp_servlet._test._droplet.__sampledroplet._jsp__tag18(__sampledroplet.java:874)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If anyone knows what is the issue please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue is at line 26 and as we only have an extract of the code I cannot tell you where that is in the above.  At a guess lProfileId is null ...

Comment: yes, in droplet profileId is coming null. I tried displaying profileId in jsp without droplet, it's working but value is not passing into droplet

Comment: Can you confirm if the Profile is transient? This can be obtained by Profile.isTransient in the JSP.

Comment: 1. Your droplet should not be globally scoped (scope=global). Droplets in my experience are usually page scoped, which is the default scope if you do not provide a $scope property. This prevents having to worry about multi-thread issues.
2. Your scope property should actually be $scope, although I don't think that this is the issue
3. There is a type; ProfileAdaptarRepository should be ProfileAdapterRepository
4. You can simplify <dsp:param name="profileId" value="${profileId}" /> to <dsp:param name="profileId" bean="Profile.id" />

Comment: @MattSidesinger droplets should generally be Globally scoped with FormHandlers being request scoped (sometimes session scoped).

Comment: @Ramyajois Do you have accessor methods for your `mProfileRepository` and as @MattSidesinger pointed out, you mistyped ProfileAdaptarRepository.

Comment: @MattSidesinger yes i did a spelling mistake. It should be ProfileAdapterRepository. Now it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

it looks like problem is here:

```
profileRepository=/atg/userProfiling/ProfileAdaptarRepository
```

Nucleus can't find this component:

1. "userprofiling" should be in lower case.
2. ProfileAdaptarRepository -> ProfileAdapterRepository